# Keep iphone unlocked when building it in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

When I use the build button in xcode to run my cordova app on the phone, if the build process take too long I get a "Device locked" error.

Is there a way or any hack I can do to keep my iphone unlocked when it's building? Is there a way to tell xcode to keep my phone unlocked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest fix for this is to disable sleep mode (for up until ~1hr) for your phone. Then you won't have to worry about it locking.

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Tap Display & Brightness.
3. Tap Auto-Lock.
4. If this option is grayed out, visit this Lock screen settings tip to
   learn what to do. Set the lock feature to a time that works for you.

Comment: I'm hoping they provide a shortcut to disable it for 1hr,2hr etc. unfortunately its not available yet.

Answer (score 5):

To fiddle with the phone's auto lock duration whenever you're working, and then changing it back to normal is not ideal for me since I use my primary phone for testing apps too. My workaround was to **run a youtube video on silent and let iOS switch it to my testing app whenever the build is ready!**

Comment: It's really a shame, that we need workarounds like this and that there isn't a solution by Apple to disable auto-lock/sleep during debugging. -.-